# broken dependencies in fuerte on Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: ros-fuerte, ubuntu-precise, ubuntu, arm-navigation

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I'm trying to install ros-fuerte-arm-navigation in 12.04 but get broken dependencies in image-common, navigation, robot-model, and visualization. The problem seems to be a conflict with oneiric versions of libassimp-dev and yaml.cpp. Here are the messages I get when I run `apt-get -f install` (to try to fix the broken dependencies):

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following extra packages will be installed:
  libassimp-dev yaml-cpp
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libassimp-dev yaml-cpp
0 upgraded, 2 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
76 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/299 kB of archives.
After this operation, 1,052 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? y
(Reading database ... 381683 files and directories currently installed.)
Unpacking yaml-cpp (from .../yaml-cpp_0.2.7-5precise-20120502-0513-+0000_amd64.deb) ...
dpkg: error processing /var/cache/apt/archives/yaml-cpp_0.2.7-5precise-20120502-0513-+0000_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/include/yaml-cpp/emitter.h', which is also in package yaml-cpp0.2.6-dev 0.2.6-4~oneiric
dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Unpacking libassimp-dev (from .../libassimp-dev_2.0.863+dfsg-2_amd64.deb) ...
dpkg: error processing /var/cache/apt/archives/libassimp-dev_2.0.863+dfsg-2_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/include/assimp/aiQuaternion.h', which is also in package assimp-dev 2.0.0.7-ubuntu1~oneiric1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/yaml-cpp_0.2.7-5precise-20120502-0513-+0000_amd64.deb
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libassimp-dev_2.0.863+dfsg-2_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

If I try to remove the oneiric versions of assimp-dev or yaml-cpp in Synaptic, then a bunch of other packages in both electric and fuerte get marked for removal. Any idea how to fix this?

Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/35630/broken-dependencies-in-fuerte-on-ubuntu-12.04/) by [somudrog](https://answers.ros.org/users/2500/somudrog/) on ROS Answers with karma: 55 on 2012-06-04

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Unfortunately, I don't know exactly what the root of the broken deps are, but a few people I know have had the exact same problem.

Either way, the tool I relied on at first was aptitude instead of apt-get, aptitude does a better job dealing with dependencies.

Also, I believe I had to first remove fuerte, then remove/reinstall yaml-cpp and libassimp-dev, then re-install fuerte.

Good luck

---

Originally posted by [phil0stine](https://answers.ros.org/users/639/phil0stine/) with karma: 682 on 2012-06-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2012-06-21**:
It looks like you have upgraded from oneiric and there's old conflicting packages still installed. You'll need to clean them up manually.

**Comment by [phil0stine](https://answers.ros.org/users/639/phil0stine/) on 2012-06-25**:
Yes the upgrade apparently caused some problems. I'm usually hesitant about manual re-configuration possibly leading down the rabbit hole, but in this case it was enough just to fix the two packages I mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I got the same problem here and I fixed with:

```
dpkg -i --force-overwrite /var/cache/apt/archives/yaml-cpp_0.2.7-5precise-20120502-0513-+0000_amd64.deb 
dpkg -i --force-overwrite /var/cache/apt/archives/libassimp-dev_2.0.863+dfsg-2_amd64.deb
```

I was really worried about this solution, because I don't like to force things like that, but it is working now.

---

Originally posted by [FabricioFC](https://answers.ros.org/users/1850/fabriciofc/) with karma: 36 on 2012-08-14

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1